# How to display an image in word from a merge field with conga composer?

Tags: ms-word, salesforce

I am trying to display an image from a url saved in a text field in salesforce in word template, that will generate a pdf.

I queried that field, but in order to display the image, it needs to be jpg or png, so I edited the text and added a .png at the end of the url text like this: {{TableStart:GetProdConfig}}{{REPLACE:QUOTEPRODUCT_CONFIGURATION_IMAGE_URL_EXTERIOR_FROM:?wid=1920:.png}}{{TableEnd:GetProdConfig}}
After that I created a bookmark pointing to that, and used it in a INCLUDEPICTURE like this: { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ Image }" } but is not working. It was easier to use Conga function IMAGE like this: {{TableStart:GetProdConfig}}{{IMAGE:QUOTEPRODUCT_CONFIGURATION_IMAGE_URL_EXTERIOR_FROM}}{{TableEnd:GetProdConfig}}, but since it needs that editing and I also should not edit the field in salesforce.